# Check if Window-Title is visible

Tags: c++, qt, window, qwidget

Short Question: Is there a Qt-way to find out whether the windowing system does show titles or not? Example:

Windows - With window titles:

[image: Windows window]

OsX - No window title:

[image: OsX Window]

I used the same code to generate these boxes:

```
QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Information", "This is an example dialog");
```

As you can see, the `"Information"` will only be shown on windows - What I want to know is how to determine if the windowing system can display window titles or not.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it, but maybe it's somwhere hidden, e.g. in the native interface?

Comment: "Show titles"? What does that mean?

Comment: if the window has the `WS_CAPTION` style and the string returned by `WM_GETTEXT` has one or more characters there's a really good chance the "window title" is being displayed.

Comment: Why would it return false on Mac? Windows on the Mac can and do have text in their title bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you interesting, here is how title to show up in your QMessageBox on Mac.

```
QMessageBox msgBox("", "This is an example dialog", QMessageBox::Information, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint);
msgBox.QDialog::setWindowTitle("Information");
msgBox.exec();
```

You can check system with `QSysInfo`. QSysInfo gives run time details about system. More can you read: [QSysInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsysinfo.html).
Here is example, where you detect IOS systems and use `Q_WS_*` macros.

```
#include <QSysInfo>
#ifdef Q_WS_MAC
switch(QSysInfo::MacintoshVersion())
{
  case QSysInfo::MV_IOS: return "IOS";//all IOS versions
  default: return "Windows";
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! But I don't want to force show it, I just want to know if it's visible or not. Windows/OsX are just an example.

Comment: @Felix I update, how can you check system in runtime. You can choise what to do with this macro.